# A derived series is an abelian series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Essentially I want to prove that $G^{(i)}/G^{(i+1)}$ is abelian for all $i$, where $G^{(i+1)} = [G^{(i)}, G^{(i)}]$.

I would also like to show the following: given an abelian series $1=G_0 \leq G_1 \leq ... \leq G_n = G$, we have $G^{(i)} \leq G_{n-i}$.

The first statement seems to be true if I can show $G/[G,G]$ is abelian.

And I'm completely clueless on how to prove the second statement.

Comment: hint: $G_{n-i} /G_{n-i-1}$ is abelian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$[G,G]$ consists of all elements of the form $g^{-1}h^{-1}gh,$ so under the natural homomorphism $\phi:G\to G/[G,G]$ we have $$ \phi(g^{-1}h^{-1}gh) = e$$ for any $g,h\in G.$

See [also.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization)